# JSP on JavaFX WebEngine

Tags: jsp, javafx, javafx-webengine

I need read information from json file which is located in user.home directory Windows 7. For this I wanted use javascript. But Javascript is not access to a local drive through java webEngine. For this I use java Class for read information from json file, and with jsp for showed result.

```
Utils.java :

public class AdminUtils{

  public String getBasStatus() {
        try {
            String userHomePath = System.getProperty("user.home");
            userHomePath = userHomePath + File.separator + "MY_PROJECT_FOLDER";
            String fileName = userHomePath + File.separator + "deviceStatus.json";
            File jsonFile = new File(fileName);
            String jsonString = null;
            jsonString = FileUtils.readFileToString(jsonFile);
            JsonElement element = new JsonParser().parse(jsonString);
            JsonObject jsonObject = element.getAsJsonObject();
            return jsonObject.get("billAcceptorStatus").toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        }
    }

    public String getPadStatus(){

        try {
            String userHomePath = System.getProperty("user.home");
            userHomePath = userHomePath + File.separator + "MY_PROJECT_FOLDER";
            String fileName = userHomePath + File.separator + "deviceStatus.json";
            File jsonFile = new File(fileName);
            String jsonString = null;
            jsonString = FileUtils.readFileToString(jsonFile);
            JsonElement element = new JsonParser().parse(jsonString);
            JsonObject jsonObject = element.getAsJsonObject();
            return jsonObject.get("pinPadStatus").toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        }

    }
}
```

this is a `deviceStatus.jsp`:

```
<%@ page import="util.AdminUtils" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-store"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Device Status</title>
    <style>
        .defaultStatus {
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            display: block;
            background: url("./../images/deviceStatusIcons/question.png") no-repeat;
            background-size: contain;
        }

        .goodStatus {
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            display: block;
            background: url("./../images/deviceStatusIcons/check.png") no-repeat;
            background-size: contain;
        }

        .badStatus {
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            display: block;
            background: url("./../images/deviceStatusIcons/delete.png") no-repeat;
            background-size: contain;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
      <%
        AdminUtils utils = new AdminUtils("username", "password");
      %>
        var basStatus = <%=utils.getBasStatus()%> ;
        var padStatus = <%=utils.getPadStatus()%> ;

        function billAcceptorStatus() {
            if (basStatus == 0) {
                $("#billAcceptorStatus").attr('class', 'goodStatus');
            }  else if (basStatus == 2) {
                $("#billAcceptorStatus").attr('class', 'badStatus');
            } else {
                $("#billAcceptorStatus").attr('class', 'defaultStatus');
            }
        }
        function pinPadStatus() {
            if (padStatus == 0) {
                $("#pinPadStatus").attr('class', 'goodStatus');
            } else if (padStatus == 2) {
                $("#pinPadStatus").attr('class', 'badStatus');
            } else {
                $("#pinPadStatus").attr('class', 'defaultStatus');
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="content">
    <div class="row">
        <div style="width:100%;height:150px;text-align: center;">
            <h2>DEVICE STATUS PAGE</h2>
        </div>
        <div style="width: 100%;height: 600px;">
            <table style="width: 60%;border-collapse:collapse;" align="center">
                <caption>DEVICE STATUSES</caption>
                <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid #adadad; background-color: #adadad">
                    <td width="10%">№</td>
                    <td width="20%">Name</td>
                    <td width="20%">Status</td>
                </tr>

                <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid #adadad;border-top: 1px solid #adadad;  background-color: gainsboro">
                    <td width="10%">1</td>
                    <td width="20%">
                        <p>Pin Pad</p>
                    </td>
                    <td width="20%">
                        <span id="pinPadStatus" class="defaultStatus"></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid #adadad;border-top: 1px solid #adadad;  background-color: gainsboro">
                    <td width="10%">2</td>
                    <td width="20%">
                        <p>Bill Acceptor</p>
                    </td>
                    <td width="20%">
                        <span id="billAcceptorStatus" class="defaultStatus"></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>
            <br/><br/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

this is a `deviceStatus.json` file:

```
{"billAcceptorStatus":"-1","pinPadStatus":"-1"}
```

this is code loading `deviceStatus.jsp` to webengine:

```
   if (Objects.equals(adminPassword.get(1), "4")) {
            if (Objects.equals(adminPassword.get(2), "5")) {
                if (Objects.equals(adminPassword.get(3), "6")) {
                    adminPassword.clear();
                    webEngine.load(AtmApplication.class.getResource("/html/deviceStatus.jsp").toExternalForm());
                    adminMode = false;
                } else loadDefaultPage();
            } else loadDefaultPage();
        }
```

But jsp file is not loaded to webEngine. If together jsp file - load html file,  webengine loaded html file. But I need load jsp file.

Answer (score 0):

JSP is a server side technology not a client side technology. It gets transformed to HTML by the server so browsers can display it. JavaFX is a client side technology and like browsers the web engine can only handle HTML files, not JSP files.